# How can I install Unity Hub on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have some troubles installing Unity Hub on my Ubuntu 22.04.
I've followed the instruction from official Unity site, but the hub seem not working well.
Only black screen is shown and nothing else.
I am very lost with it! :(
The following codes has been runned:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://hub.unity3d.com/linux/repos/deb stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/unityhub.list'
wget -qO - https://hub.unity3d.com/linux/keys/public | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install unityhub
```

Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Lately I had the following error:
ERROR: Licensing SDK logging callback is not registered. Please use 'registerLoggingAdapter' function from the SDK to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**To resolve this issue you can install libssl1.1**

I was also facing the same issue so **I made an script** that make it easy to install Unity hub on Ubuntu latest versions

```
#!/bin/bash
#Lib issue Ubuntu
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.0g-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb
chmod +x libssl1.1_1.1.0g-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.0g-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb
echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/impish-security.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl1.1

#unityhub
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://hub.unity3d.com/linux/repos/deb stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/unityhub.list'
wget -qO - https://hub.unity3d.com/linux/keys/public | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install unityhub
```

**HOW TO USE BASH**

1. Make a file with `install.sh` on Desktop.
2. Paste this code on `install.sh` file.
3. Open Terminal in `"Desktop" location`.
4. type `chmod +x install.sh` then press Enter.
5. type `./install.sh` and press Enter.
6. After all the installing, Restart PC and then run UnityHub.

Comment: Latest address for libssl is http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.23_amd64.deb

Answer (score 3):

For installing libssl1.1, neither of the two answers posted above work anymore. I was able to find a modern answer here: https://gist.github.com/joulgs/c8a85bb462f48ffc2044dd878ecaa786

Essentially you run the following commands to install libssl1.1.

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.0g-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.0g-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

> - Unity Editor fails to launch and complains about "no usable version of libssl was found"
> - Ubuntu 22.04 now ships with libssl3 by default and does not include libssl1.1. Unity currently uses .NET5 which requires libssl1.1. To
>   work around this issue you can install libssl1.1 from an older Ubuntu
>   release
> - https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libssl1.1/download
> - In a terminal:

```
echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/impish-security.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl1.1
```